# Publishing windows executable on GitHub

Tags: github, exe

I have a Windows application that I want to publish on GitHub. I've compiled the program and uploaded the `.exe` file as a binary on the releases page.

The problem is, that the Chrome browser doesn't want to download it, as it is an executable and treats it as dangerous. Even if I'll force it to download, Windows Defender prevents me from running it. The same happens even if I'll put this file inside a `.zip` archive (the difference is that Chrome says the file is rarely downloaded and might be dangerous).

Is there any way to allow users to safely download executables from the GitHub release?

Comment: Signing the executable might help...at least with windows...

Comment: @dan1st never did that before. Will Windows respect a self-signed free certificate or do I have to get a paid one?

Comment: I don't know how signing of `exe`s work.